# How do i search by ID in json file?

Tags: javascript, json

so let's say i have this JSON file:

```json
{
  "1": {
    "name": "some random name 1",
    "nickname": "some random nickname 1"
  },
  "2": {
    "name": "some random name 2",
    "nickname": "some random nickname 2"
  }
}
```

And i need function that searches by ID,(`"1": / "2":` is ID basically) and saves it in variable. (Using Javascript). I just don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just standard bracket notation for this...?

```js
var object = {
  "1": {
    "name": "some random name 1",
    "nickname": "some random nickname 1"
  },
  "2": {
    "name": "some random name 2",
    "nickname": "some random nickname 2"
  }
}

console.log(object["1"]);
console.log(object["2"]);
```